# How do I configure a dark mode icon for a keyboard layout

Tags: icons, osx-yosemite

A custom keyboard layout can be installed on OSX by dropping the `.keylayout` file along with a `.icns` file into `/Library/Keyboard Layouts`. However, when I enable Yosemite's dark mode, the icon vanishes from the menu bar (although the area is still clickable).

This icon represents the input menu that can be enabled in the keyboard preferences. The OSX API allows one to specify an alternative icon for dark mode, but how do I specify this for a keyboard layout?

Comment: [See here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tunnelblick-discuss/0JU-UQHVJDY) for possible answer.